# Postgres не слышит

Tags: macos, postgresql

Для меня остается загадкой причина отсутствия слуха у PostgreSQL. Работал, все было хорошо, перезапустил компьютер и слух база потеряла. Работаю на OS X.

- Гуглил на тему ручного запуска
     postres.
- Ковырял файлы конфигурации,
     не помогло.
- Работаю на порту 3612.
- В прошлый раз, сразу после первой
     установки, помогла переустановка с
     нуля.

Comment: Что значит потеряла слух? К отоларингологу обращались? Что говорите `ps ax` ? Что говорит `netstat -l` ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/M52kuvfT

Comment: Ох. У меня под linux'ом `netstat -l` выдаёт список портов, которые кто-то слушает. У Вас, видимо, нужно задавать другие параметры. Что хотел посоветовать: (1) поверить запущен ли postgres ( `ps ax | grep postgres` ) (2) посмотреть, слушает ли он заданный Вами порт (netstat)

Comment: >причина отсутствия слуха у PostgreSQL

прям язык метафор какой-то

Comment: ~ mac$ ps ax | grep postgres 
23194 s000  R+     0:00.00 grep postgres

Я думаю это значит, что постгрес не запущен.
Тогда вопрос в том как его запустить.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. У меня -- `sudo service postgresql start`. Как у Вас (кстати, у Вас OS X?) -- не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

Запустил эту свинью! /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/ start

Возникли проблемы с правами, нужно запускать от имени создателя папки.

Такая ошибка: "Permissions should be u=rwx (0700)." решилась закрытием всякого доступа всем пользователям, только активному чтение и запись.

Такая: "The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory." копированием папки postgres и запуск производился уже из нее.